# Does ArgumentsOptions do anything we couldn't do without it?

Tags: function-construction, programming, language-design

[ArgumentsOptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArgumentsOptions.html) was new in version 12.2. I looked at the application on that page, and it makes code very difficult to understand. What if anything does ArgumentsOptions do for us that we couldn't do before?